# UITextField delegate methods not being called in iPhone 6s

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a UIViewcontroller with a UIView which has as subviews the uitextfield and a uiimageview. I am testing my app in iphone X and iPhone 6s and iphone SE 2nd generation. The UITextField delegate is working on iPhone X but not in iPhone 6s and iphone se. I have set IBoutlet in xcode to the textfield. Any thoughts? What am i missing?

```
@interface TagsViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tagsTextField;
@end

@implementation TagsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tagsTextField.delegate=self;
    self.tagsTextField.enabled=true;
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.text = [textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSString *trimmedText = [textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    textField.text = trimmedText;
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    return NO;
}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    return YES;
}


@end
```

Comment: What iOS version is your `6s` running? Works fine for me on `6s iOS 13.3` (simulator -- I don't have a physical 6s device).

Comment: @DonMag I did the viewcontroller from the beginning and it worked! It had something to do with the constraints! The code was the same! It is working now thanks for your suggestion!